# Which scholars say ijma of ummah is infallible?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith, usool-ul-fiqh

I was told initially that 2 things are infallible, Quran and the sunnah.

Later on I learnt 3 things are infallible

A. Quran.
B. Sunnah.
C. Ijma of companions (proof was given as 4:115)

When I came across a report, it made me think if ijma of ummah is infallible.

> ***Whatever the Muslims view as good is good to Allah, and whatever they view as evil is evil to Allah***.”

Source: Musnad Ahmad 3600

Since, the view of Allah is infallible, face value it appears the ijma of muslims is infallible as per report of musnad Ahmed.

Hence the main question which muslims scholars say the ijma(consensus) of Muslim ummah is infallible.

Comment: The question seems unclear. By definition, those who consider ijma evidence, which is all the Sunni scholars, consider Ijma infallible. Why else would it be evidence?

Comment: Ijma of sahaba is infallible, where do scholars say ijma of ummah is infallible?

Comment: What do you think it means for ijma' to be a proof in the religion?

Comment: I'm not able to understand, can you please elaborate

Comment: It depends on whether you include Shia scholars among Muslims or exclude them.